# Pixelated display on hp laptop

Tags: display, gpu, pixels

I have an HP pavilion gaming 15-dk0020na laptop and yesterday I've got this issue with the display.
I do not know if it is something regarding the GPU or pixels. It looks pixelated.

Photograph -

[image]

Screenshot -

[image]

Comment: Looks fine in a screenshot.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't know how, are you sure?

Comment: Blown up to jumbo size & screen-snapped again - https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8hkG.png - looks fairly forgivable to me for that kind of size.

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me too.

Comment: Check it now guys

Answer (score 1):

Based on the new screenshot, it is likely a physical issue

- loose display connector/wiring
- faulty graphics card

Try these troubleshooting methods:

- change screen resolution
- update display drivers

Comment: 8 months and I don't have any warranty anymore

Comment: The thing is that I still have a portion of the screen that looks normal like before

Comment: The fact that you still have some visibility and usability of your screen proves that the ribbon cable to the display might be loose or faulty. I'm afraid is something that needs to be checked, unless you have a spare display ribbon cable for your laptop lying around. For your case I highly recommend getting it looked at!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, yeah - that's not so much 'pixellated' as 'broken'.

It's not a software issue, you proved that with the original screenshot, enlargement below.

That's a hardware fail. Either cable or screen itself.
Take it to a professional.

[image]